# XAMPP Apache redirect my virtualhost to /dashboard

Tags: php, apache

I config my apache hostname and virtualhost in XAMPP on Mac.

But, when I access to host url, xampp redirects me to /dashboard:
mydomain.dev/dashboard

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
# Virtual Hosts

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/web_frikinow/public"
    ServerName mydomain.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my /etc/hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 mydomain.dev
127.0.0.1 Funny-Frontend # added by Apache Friends XAMPP
```

Whats is the problem?

Comment: darn it, I use similar logic here on my local network - including 'personal domain names' - 'cos we can. Hmm, it looks ok. Add an entry for the 'index' files? i.e index.php index.html etc? What files do you have in that directory? Can the web server user access that directory?

Comment: do you have any scripts in DocumentRoot?

Comment: Ryan Vincent I enabled all permisions 777 to my files...

Comment: I don´t understand, where is the <Directory></Directory> code?

Comment: Example entry  that works  here [Pastebin - Example virtual host](http://pastebin.com/kfMqGsBD). The entries must be in your 'hosts' file - which you know already. Sadly, I use XAMPP on windows.

Comment: Ohh man, I find my fail!, I incomment this module # Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf in httpd.conf

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is uncomment this module in the file httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: what is location of `httpd.conf:` file? there are file `httpd-somthing.cong`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to just restart apache under the XAMPP control panel.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem also other sequential issues.

How I solved:
First thing first,

1. You should change User permission which is daemon as standard. Change it to your username. You can see your name on terminal username@...

/Applications/XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf

From:

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

To

```
User username
Group daemon
```

2. Uncomment vhost line if you add virtual hosts to this vhost configuration.

/Applications/XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf

```
#Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

3. (Optional) If your files are not located on htdocs you will probably get same problem with me. I am adding my folder which will contain my all projects on there as allowed folder.

/Applications/XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf

Add this line

```
<Directory "/Users/username/foldername">
    # 
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #   
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    # XAMPP
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    
    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    #AllowOverride None
    # since XAMPP 1.4:
    AllowOverride All
     
    # 
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #   
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Save it and restart the apache web server on XAMPP. For 3rd option, there are other solutions also which can help you.